# fragment setUserVisibleHint is not called in Viewpager inside anotherViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a fragment with **ViewPager of 4 tabs** and in the **4th tab I have another Viewpager with 3 tabs** such that if whenever I *switch my topviewPagerTab(one with 4 tabs) then the setUserVisiblehint of fragments that was in the sub viewPager(with 3 tabs) is not called*.

So in reality the fragments in the sub viewPager of 4th/last tab is not visible to user but the **setUserVisibleHint()** is not called so it my boolean value *isMyPageVisible that was set at visiting that fragment* is always true for them unless I switch tabs in the subviewPager

```
boolean isPageVisible = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isPageVisible = isVisibleToUser;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UserAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public UserAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    public void clearFragment()
    {
        fragments.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }


    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isUserVisibleHint)
    {
        if(viewPagerPojos != null && viewPagerPojos.size() > 0)
        {
            for(ViewPagerPojo viewPagerPojo : viewPagerPojos)
            {
                viewPagerPojo.getFragment().setUserVisibleHint(isUserVisibleHint);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and in each and every fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible);
    if (mAdaptor != null) {
     mAdaptor.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible);
    }
}
```

and in sub fragments

```
boolean isPageVisible;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleHint) 
{
    isPageVisible = this.isVisible() && isVisibleHint;
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isPageVisible);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you move between outer fragments the setUserVisibleHint for the current fragment showing in the inner viewpager is not called.
Extend your FragmentStatePagerAdaptor

```
public class CustomPagerAdaptor extends FragmentStatePagerAdaptor {
    private Fragment primary;

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        primary = (Fragment)object;
    }

    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisible) {
        if (primary != null){
            primary.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the outer fragment pass the setUserVisibleHint through:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible);
    if (mAdaptor != null) mAdaptor.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible);
}
```

Comment: So do we have to do as externally and there is no other way of doing this right?

Comment: Then if open my 4th tab of main viewpager then all the fragments inside subViewPager will be set to visible eventhough some of them is not...